# How do I secure my tornado python file?

Tags: security, nginx, tornado

With security in mind, what is the best practice for storing my main.py on a web server? For example, is it safe to place my main.py in /var/www/mysite.com/public_html or should I place it in /var/www/mysite.com.

I am a first time subscriber to a virtual private server and I am running Nginx as a reverse proxy to a Tornado web server. If you are not familiar with Tornado, main.py is the python file that starts my Tornado  web application.

Below is an example of how I plan on organizing my files.

- /var

  - /www

    - /mysite.com

      - **main.py (Is it safer here?)**
      - /public_html

        - index.html
        - **main.py (Or is it fine here?)**
    - /mysecondsite.com

      - /public_html

        - index.html
    - /mythirdsite.com

      - /public_html

        - index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to keep things out of public_html unless you specifically need them there.  I would recommend setting up a separate directory next to public_html for the application code:

```
/var/www/mysite.com/app/main.py
/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/*
```

Comment: Great input Ben, you make a good point. There is no reason the public user would need to view this file so I will make a separate directory as you suggested.